# Checkstyle - check only method in interface

Tags: checkstyle

Is it possible apply JavadocMethod checker only on methods in interface? (not in implementation classes)

Answer (score 3):

We had plan to implement it also, keep at eye on [issue](https://github.com/sevntu-checkstyle/sevntu.checkstyle/issues/70), not sure when we fix it, or welcome to provide patch we already have full infrastructure for development.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java 6, you can annotate the implementing method with `@Override`, which will tell the JavadocMethod checker not to require a Javadoc comment. Quoting the JavadocMethod docs:

> Javadoc is not required on a method that is tagged with the `@Override` annotation.

The documentation continues stating that you need Java 6. In Java 5, you can still use `{@inheritdoc}`, which is better than nothing:

> However under Java 5 it is not possible to mark a method required for an interface (this was *corrected* under Java 6). Hence Checkstyle supports using the convention of using a single `{@inheritDoc}` tag instead of all the other tags.

The built-in Eclipse code formatter can automatically add the `@Override` annotations for you, so this should be pretty much what you need.