# How to enforce Javadoc comments for interfaces using Checkstyle?

Tags: java, interface, abstract-class, checkstyle, sevntu-checkstyle

I'd like to configure Checkstyle in a way, that it enforces Javadocs for interfaces, but not for general classes.

The most promising candidate module seemed to be [`JavadocMethod`](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_javadoc.html#JavadocMethod), but I couldn't find an option to limit it to interfaces (and abstract classes).

Comment: Duplicate of [Checkstyle - check only method in interface](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13271326/1005481)